# Not dual booting with Ubuntu Linux 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, boot

After installing Ubuntu Linux 12.04 LTS (from CD) side by side with Windows 7, why am I not getting dual boot? Each time I restart or shut down my laptop, Windows 7 automatically loads. What to do? I cannot see any bootloader that pops up each time I restart or shutdown.

Thank you. Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

your problem happen to me when i install windows 8 to my laptop (i have ubuntu then i install windows8).
if you install ubuntu perfectly and do not get any problem, 
maybe this link can help you
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 0):

@ fikriarroisi - windows 8 comes with UEFI so unless the OS you want to install has a key, you will not be able to run it. refer to - http://windows.microsoft.com/en-IN/windows-8/what-uefi . But, apparently, ubuntu 13.04 64-bit version comes with EFI, so you can dual boot b/w windows 8 and ubuntu 13.04.

as for the original question, try downloading GRUB - http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/grub-download.html, burning it onto a CD or a pendrive (like it's usually done for linux installation) and see if you need to install the grub loader.